# RedHat Cluster 6 node won't see shared volume group

Tags: redhat, cluster, lvm, cluster-shared-volumes

I try to create a shared clvm volume group shared between 2 nodes of a Red Hat Cluster 6.

Here is the procedure I followed:

```
[root@node1 ~]# pvcreate /dev/mapper/mpathab
[root@node1 ~]# vgcreate -c y  data1_vg /dev/mapper/mpathab
[root@node1 ~]# vgs
VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
data1_vg   1   0   0 wz--nc 50.00g 50.00g
```

After this point I expect this vg becomes visible in other node. But nothing there:

```
[root@node2 ~]# vgs
[root@node2 ~]#
```

I tried to restart clvmd service, cluster, rebooted both nodes, but it didn't change. BTW cluster status looks fine:

```
[root@node2 ~]#
[root@node2 ~]# clustat
Cluster Status for myCluster00 @ Sat Aug  8 22:01:24 2015
Member Status: Quorate

 Member Name                                                     ID   Status
 ------ ----                                                     ---- ------
 node1                                                             1    Online
 node2                                                             2  Online, Local
[root@node2 ~]#

[root@node1 ~]# service clvmd status
clvmd (pid  25975) is running...
Clustered Volume Groups: data1_vg
clustered Logical Volumes: (none)
[root@node1 ~]#

[root@node2 ~]# service clvmd status
clvmd (pid  25917) is running...
Clustered Volume Groups: (none)
Active clustered Logical Volumes: (none)
[root@node2 ~]#
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: Is cluster locking enabled in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` ?

Comment: Yes. Both is set to 3:
locking_type = 3